# Counting - Combinations of $4$ digit numbers and their sums.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We form all possible $4$-digit numbers using $1,2,3,4,5$.

1. How many such numbers are possible?
2. What is the sum of all these 4-digit numbers?
3. How do the answers change if we use $1,1,2,3,4$ instead.

**My try**:

1. $5$ choices for each position. Therefore $5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5= 625$
2. $4$ choices as $1$ is repeated $2$ times. Therefore $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4 = 256$.

I am stuck on part (2). I have no idea about it.

Comment: I believe you misinterpreted the question.  The third part of the question suggests that the listed digits are to be used *without* repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have misinterpreted the question.  The third part of the question suggests that the listed digits are to be used *without* repetition.  With that interpretation in mind, let's proceed.

> How many four digit numbers can be formed using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$?

To form a four-digit number, we select four of the five digits, then place them in order, which can be done in 
$$\binom{5}{4} \cdot 4! = 5 \cdot 4 = 120$$
ways.

> What is the sum of these $4$-digit numbers?

By symmetry, each of the five digits is used in each position 
$$\frac{120}{5} = 24$$
times.  Hence, the sum is 
$$24(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)(10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0) = 24 \cdot 15 \cdot 1111 = 399 960$$

> How do the answers change if we use $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$?

There are two possibilities.

1. There are four distinct digits.
2. The digit $1$ is used twice.

There are $4! = 24$ ways of arranging the four distinct digits $1, 2, 3, 4$.

If the digit $1$ is used twice, we must select two of the four positions to be occupied by a $1$.  We then have three choices for the leftmost open position and two choices for the remaining position.  Hence, the number of four-digit numbers that can be formed using the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$ if the digit $1$ is repeated is 
$$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 36$$
Hence, the number of four-digit numbers that can be formed using the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$ is
$$4! + \binom{4}{2} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 24 + 36 = 60$$

To determine the sum of these $60$ numbers, we consider cases.

Four distinct digits are used:  By symmetry, each of the four digits $1, 2, 3, 4$ is used in each position 
$$\frac{4!}{4} = \frac{24}{4} = 6$$
times.  Hence, the sum of the four-digit numbers formed with the four distinct digits $1, 2, 3, 4$ is 
$$6(1 + 2 + 3 + 4)(10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0) = 6 \cdot 10 \cdot 1111 = 66660$$
In each of the $36$ four-digit numbers formed with the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$ in which the digit $1$ is used twice, half of the digits used are $1$'s. By symmetry, the digit $1$ must appear
$$\frac{36}{2} = 18$$
times in each position.  By symmetry, the digits $2, 3, 4$ must appear 
$$\frac{18}{3} = 6$$
times in each position.  Thus, the sum of the four-digit numbers formed using the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$ in which $1$ appears twice is 
\begin{align*}
18(10^3 & + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0) + 6(2 + 3 + 4)(10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0)\\ 
& = 18 \cdot 1111 + 6 \cdot 9 \cdot 1111\\ 
& = 18 \cdot 1111 + 54 \cdot 1111\\
& = 72 \cdot 1111\\ 
& = 79992
\end{align*}
Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, the sum of all the four-digit numbers that can be formed using the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 4$ is 
$$66660 + 79992 = 146652$$

Comment: Yes, this is a valid point. +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that repetition of digits is allowed (although the formulation of question 3. suggests the contrary, see other answer), you correctly found that there are $625$ 4-digit numbers with the digits $1,2,3,4,5$. These numbers are of the form $$10^3d_{k,3}+10^2d_{k,2}+10^1d_{k,1}+10^0d_{k,0}$$ with $k=1,2,\dots625$ and therefore their sum is equal to $$\sum_{k=1}^{625}\left(10^3d_{k,3}+10^2d_{k,2}+10^1d_{k,1}+10^0d_{k,0}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{3}10^j\sum_{k=1}^{625}d_{k,j}$$ Now, due to symmetry each digit is used in each position exactly as frequently as any other number, i.e. $625/5=125$ times, giving that $$\sum_{k=1}^{625}d_{k,j}=125(1+2+3+4+5)=125(15)=1875$$ for any $j=0,1,2,3$. Hence 
\begin{align}\sum_{j=0}^{3}10^j\sum_{k=1}^{625}d_{k,j}&=\sum_{j=0}^{3}10^j\cdot1875=\left(10^3+10^2+10^1+10^0\right)\cdot1875=2083125\end{align}
You need to this also for question 3. where you need simply to change $5$ to $1$. Your answer $(256)$ in the first part of 3. is also correct.

Comment: How can it be only 7500?

Comment: I calculated the sum of the digits, not the sum of the numbers, but this is not the question. Sorry, let me correct this.

Comment: @max Sorry for the confusion before. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I believe you misinterpreted the question.  The third part of the question suggests that the listed digits are to be used *without* repetition.

Comment: I suggest that you add a statement at the beginning of your answer stating that you interpreted the question to mean that digits could be repeated.

Comment: Yes, I did, see my edit. @N. F. Taussig